# How does VimDiff works?

Tags: algorithm

I have searched on net but everywhere use and example of VimDiff was there.
Can someone please explain me how does vimdiff works ?

Basically the problem is we have two documents at system1 and syste2 has only document no1.
now i need to compute some diff over two docs at system1 so that diff can be shipped over network and then we can generate doc2 using diff and doc1.

Comment: Are you asking how VimDiff works, or how to use it?

Comment: You could search for *Longest Common Subsequence*

Comment: Can you use the standard `diff(1)` and `patch(1)` tool instead?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your goals, this is probably a solved problem.  I would recommend using one of the following:

1. If your documents are flat text files: diff and patch
2. If your documents are binary data: rdiff
3. If 2, but you'd like the diffing and patching to be handled for you: rsync

Regarding the question as asked, it looks like vimdiff uses an external program (typically diff, but can be specified).  An explanation of how diff works is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm